# C#: If-Else Troubles

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an issue with my if else statement to where it will only display the else output and not the if output.

```
default:
    if (GradeVar >= 10) {
        Console.WriteLine("That grade is a perfect score. Well done!");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("That grade is not passing.");
    }
    break;
```

Here's the specific code I am talking about; its for a program to display certain messages for grades.

Comment: Dont use goto, and the only reasonable explanation is that GradeVar is never greater than 10

Comment: Please learn how to use the debugger to inspect your code in real time

Comment: @Saruman Where is he using 'goto'?

Comment: Please add you full code because you issue is not clear

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII good point, i saw default and got the cold shivers

Answer (score 0):

### The Simple Answer

`GradeVar` is always less than or equal to `9`.

---

However, we need a [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to truly understand what is going wrong. So far we can tell that you're most likely in a `switch` structure, and probably inside either a `method` or a `loop` in which `GradeVar` is a parameter, local variable, or property. It would be a good idea to revise your question and include the following:

- Where `GradeVar` is declared.
- Anywhere `GradeVar`'s value is modified, prior to the location in code you've already supplied.
- Any additional parameters, local variables, or properties that assist in the modification of `GradeVar`.
- Anything else we may need to reproduce the issue at hand.

I hope this helps you get the answer you need, and wish you the best of luck in your endeavors.